# Searching through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

**My situation:**

I'm working on a large Rails app, with yaml i18n for multiple languages. Things get added here and there, or some i18n just gets forgotten about, so we end up with bits of i18n missing here there and everywhere, which can be difficult to catch.

When the app doesn't find a translation in a certain language for a given bit of text, it generates something like this in the HTML :

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.path.to.thing_requiging_translation">Thing requiring translation</span>
```

---

What I would like is a way to search through the generated source code of all the pages of the application and return a list of all the title tags, eg. `translation missing: en.path.to.translation`, so I can go through and easily add all the missing translations and be sure I haven't missed any.

I've had a decent search and couldn't find anything that already exists to do this - does anybody know of anything?

As for my own approach, we were thinking of using Phantom.js or something similar to automate the process, but I really wanted to check there's not a way of doing this already, or an easier way than what I'd considered.

Comment: Why do you want to fix this in front-end level? You can use conditionals in your view files I guess?

Comment: I suppose it's to keep the view files clean - and seeing as so much of the application has already been built, it would be a bit of a pain to go back and add all the conditionals in. Also partly curiosity - to see if it would be possible to do it this way.

Comment: You can't reliably recreate all your views without the backing controller calls that render it.  Which means, you'll need to run through all code branches at your controller level...  A simpler approach may be to search your code base for references to the `t` method, and then compare those to what's in your en.yml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) is a gem that does just this with static analysis:

[image]